# printing Gridview with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I would like to print the contents af a GridView using jQuery:

```
var prtwin = window.open('', 'PrintGridViewData', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,tollbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
prtwin.document.write($('#GridView')[0].outerHTML);
prtwin.document.close();
prtwin.focus();
prtwin.print();
prtwin.close();
```

this procedure works, but does not print the header; so I can add:

```
jQuery('#GridView tbody tr:first').before('<tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>col4</td><td>col5</td><td>col6</td></tr>');
```

but this code **also** adds a line to the Gridview displayed in the page; and  this is **not** required. 
Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the GridView with a `<div>` with an ID and get that content to the print window.

```
<div id="printMe">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And then in the script

```
prtwin.document.write($('#printMe').html());
```